# How to store old hydraulic disc brakes?

Tags: brakes, storage, preventative-maintenance, rotor

Since I'm replacing my old Shimano M446 hydraulic disc brakes with new ones, I'm wondering is there a way to properly store disc brakes that are not in use (disassembled from bike frame)? At the moment, I'm not sure if I'm going to sell them or keep them but anyway I would like to keep them in working order.

Here are some of questions:

- Should I keep system closed (filled with oil), replace old oil (probably needs replacing anyway) or drain it completely?
- Should brake pads stay in calipers or remove them and place bleed blocks?
- How to handle brake hose so it doesn't break or change shape?
- How to store rotors so they don't bend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are buying new brakes - the best thing to do would be to store your old brakes in the same manner you receive the new brakes.

And that would also be re-using the existing packaging.

I'm sure the logistics in getting newly manufactured brakes from the production line to the retail counter / customer involves many months of transportation and storage. So you should be absolutely fine mimicking this.